# Consuta sql Filas a Columnas

Tags: sql-server

Hola buen dia tengo una consulta que me trae el resultado en filas de la siguiente manera

```
    SUC CAJA_CORTE  FECHA_CORTE EFECTIVO    TARJETA VALE    CHEQUE  DEPOSIT ANTICIPO    MONEDERO
      3     CAJA1   01/02/2019     1760      200    322.04    56      490.01     560    68
```

asi es como me lo trae la consulta pero lo quiero presentar en columnas:

```
efectivo 1760
tarjeta  200
vale     322.04
cheque    56
deposito   490.01
anticipo    560
monedero   68
```

asi tengo la query:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    --SELECT CORTES.C1 AS SUC   
    SELECT CORTES.C1 AS SUC, CORTES.C2 AS GENERO, CORTES.C3 AS NATURALEZA, CORTES.C4 AS GRUPO, CORTES.C5 AS TIPO, CORTES.C9 AS CAJA_CORTE, FORMAT(CORTES.C13,'d','eu') AS FECHA_CORTE
            --CORTES.C9 AS CAJA_CORTE
          ,SUM((ISNULL(EFECTIVO.EFECTIVO,0)-ISNULL(GENERAL.CAMBIO,0)-ISNULL(DEV_EFE.DEV_EFEC,0)+ISNULL(ANTICIPO.ANTICIPO,0) +ISNULL(RETIROS.ING,0)+ISNULL(RETIROS.RETI,0)- ISNULL(RETIROS.RETIDD,0))) AS EFECTIVO,
           SUM(GENERAL.TARJETA) AS TARJETA, SUM(GENERAL.VALE) AS VALE, SUM(GENERAL.CHEQUE) AS CHEQUE, SUM(GENERAL.DEPOSITO) AS DEPOSITO, SUM((GENERAL.ANTICIPO-ISNULL(ANTICIPO.ANTICIPO,0))) AS ANTICIPO
          ,SUM(GENERAL.MONEDERO) AS MONEDERO
    FROM KDPOS AS CORTES 
    LEFT JOIN KDUV AS VENDEDORES ON VENDEDORES.C2=CORTES.C10
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT EFECTIVO.C11 AS CAJAR, EFECTIVO.C44 AS FOLIOR, SUM(CAST( EFECTIVO.C88 AS DECIMAL(15,2))) AS EFECTIVO 
        FROM KDM1 AS EFECTIVO 
        WHERE EFECTIVO.C2='U' AND EFECTIVO.C3='D' AND EFECTIVO.C4='10' AND EFECTIVO.C5='1' AND EFECTIVO.C88<>''
        GROUP BY EFECTIVO.C11, EFECTIVO.C44
        UNION ALL
        SELECT EFECTIVO_RAP.C11 AS CAJAR, EFECTIVO_RAP.C44 AS FOLIOR, SUM(CAST( EFECTIVO_RAP.C88 AS DECIMAL(15,2))) AS EFECTIVO 
        FROM KDM1 AS EFECTIVO_RAP 
        WHERE EFECTIVO_RAP.C2='U' AND EFECTIVO_RAP.C3='D' AND EFECTIVO_RAP.C4='75' AND EFECTIVO_RAP.C5='1'AND EFECTIVO_RAP.C88<>''
        GROUP BY EFECTIVO_RAP.C11, EFECTIVO_RAP.C44
    ) AS EFECTIVO ON EFECTIVO.CAJAR=CORTES.C9 AND EFECTIVO.FOLIOR=CORTES.C6
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT DOCTOS.C11 AS CAJA, DOCTOS.C44 AS FOLIO_CAJA,
            SUM(CAST((CASE WHEN DOCTOS.C86='' THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), REPLACE(DOCTOS.C86, CHAR(0), '')) END) AS DECIMAL(15,2))) AS TARJETA
            ,SUM(CAST((CASE WHEN DOCTOS.C87='' THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), REPLACE(DOCTOS.C87, CHAR(0), '')) END) AS DECIMAL(15,2))) AS VALE
            ,SUM(DOCTOS.C49) AS CHEQUE
            ,SUM(CAST((CASE WHEN DOCTOS.C82='' THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), REPLACE(DOCTOS.C82, CHAR(0), '')) END) AS DECIMAL(15,2))) AS DEPOSITO
            ,SUM(CAST((CASE WHEN DOCTOS.C136='' THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), REPLACE(DOCTOS.C136, CHAR(0), '')) END) AS DECIMAL(15,2))) AS ANTICIPO
            ,SUM(CAST((CASE WHEN DOCTOS.C92='' THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), REPLACE(DOCTOS.C92, CHAR(0), '')) END) AS DECIMAL(15,2))) AS MONEDERO
            ,SUM(CAST((CASE WHEN DOCTOS.C84='' THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), REPLACE(DOCTOS.C84, CHAR(0), '')) END) AS DECIMAL(15,2))) AS CAMBIO
        FROM KDM1 AS DOCTOS
        WHERE DOCTOS.C9='20190201' --AND DOCTOS.C44='0000104'
        GROUP BY DOCTOS.C11, DOCTOS.C44
    ) AS GENERAL ON GENERAL.CAJA=CORTES.C9 AND GENERAL.FOLIO_CAJA=CORTES.C6
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT DEVOLUCIONES.C11 AS CAJA_DEV, DEVOLUCIONES.C44 AS FOLIO_DEV, SUM(DEVOLUCIONES.C16) AS DEV_EFEC 
        FROM KDM1 AS DEVOLUCIONES 
        WHERE DEVOLUCIONES.C2='U' AND DEVOLUCIONES.C3='A' AND DEVOLUCIONES.C4='20' AND DEVOLUCIONES.C5='1'
        GROUP BY DEVOLUCIONES.C11, DEVOLUCIONES.C44
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DEVOLUCIONES_RAP.C11 AS CAJA_DEV, DEVOLUCIONES_RAP.C44 AS FOLIO_DEV, SUM(DEVOLUCIONES_RAP.C16) AS DEV_EFEC 
        FROM KDM1 AS DEVOLUCIONES_RAP
        WHERE DEVOLUCIONES_RAP.C2='U' AND DEVOLUCIONES_RAP.C3='A' AND DEVOLUCIONES_RAP.C4='76' AND DEVOLUCIONES_RAP.C5='1'
        GROUP BY DEVOLUCIONES_RAP.C11, DEVOLUCIONES_RAP.C44
    ) AS DEV_EFE ON DEV_EFE.CAJA_DEV=CAJA AND DEV_EFE.FOLIO_DEV=CORTES.C6
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT ANTICIPOS.C11 AS CAJA_ANTI, ANTICIPOS.C44 AS FOLIO_ANTI, SUM(CAST( ANTICIPOS.C88 AS FLOAT)) AS ANTICIPO 
        FROM KDM1 AS ANTICIPOS
        WHERE ANTICIPOS.C2='U' AND ANTICIPOS.C3='A' AND ANTICIPOS.C4='40' AND ANTICIPOS.C5='1'
        GROUP BY ANTICIPOS.C11, ANTICIPOS.C44
    ) AS ANTICIPO ON ANTICIPO.CAJA_ANTI=CORTES.C9 AND ANTICIPO.FOLIO_ANTI=CORTES.C6
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT RETIROS.C1 AS CVE_SUC, RETIROS.C2 AS GEN, RETIROS.C3 AS NAT, RETIROS.C4 AS GPO, RETIROS.C5 AS TIP, RETIROS.C6 AS FOL, ISNULL(CASE WHEN RETIROS.C8='RETIRO' THEN (CASE WHEN RETIROS.C20='1' THEN (SUM(RETIROS.C9)*-1) END) END, 0) AS RETIDD, 
        ISNULL(CASE WHEN RETIROS.C8='RETIRO' THEN (CASE WHEN RETIROS.C20<>'1' THEN (SUM(RETIROS.C9)*-1) END) END, 0) AS RETI,
        ISNULL(CASE WHEN RETIROS.C8<>'RETIRO' THEN SUM(RETIROS.C9) END, 0) AS ING
        FROM KDM7 AS RETIROS
        GROUP BY RETIROS.C1, RETIROS.C2, RETIROS.C3, RETIROS.C4, RETIROS.C5, RETIROS.C6, RETIROS.C8, RETIROS.C20
    ) AS RETIROS ON RETIROS.CVE_SUC=CORTES.C1 AND RETIROS.GEN=CORTES.C2 AND RETIROS.NAT=CORTES.C3  AND RETIROS.GPO=CORTES.C4 AND RETIROS.TIP=CORTES.C5 AND RETIROS.FOL=CORTES.C6
    WHERE --CORTES.C1='"&suc&"' AND CORTES.C2='"&gen&"' AND CORTES.C3='"&nat&"' AND CORTES.C4='"&gpo&"' AND CORTES.C5='"&tip&"' AND 
    CORTES.C13='20190201' AND CORTES.C16='0' AND CORTES.C6='0000104'
    GROUP BY  CORTES.C1, CORTES.C2, CORTES.C3, CORTES.C4, CORTES.C5, CORTES.C9, FORMAT(CORTES.C13,'d','eu')
    --GROUP BY  CORTES.C1
) DATOS
```

si aguien me puede apoyar por favor

Comment: Mira UNPIVOT aquí, igual te es de utilidad: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como tu consulta era muy compleja, la he metido en una tabla en memoria primero, para luego poder tratarla. Creo que hace lo que buscas.

```
declare @datos as table (
SUC int, 
CAJA_CORTE char(10), 
FECHA_CORTE datetime, 
EFECTIVO money, 
TARJETA money, 
VALE money, 
CHEQUE money, 
DEPOSIT money, 
ANTICIPO money, 
MONEDERO money
)

-- Metemos tu consulta dentro de la tabla en memoria
insert into @datos 
--SELECT CORTES.C1 AS SUC   
    SELECT CORTES.C1 AS SUC, CORTES.C2 AS GENERO, CORTES.C3 AS NATURALEZA, CORTES.C4 AS GRUPO, CORTES.C5 AS TIPO, CORTES.C9 AS CAJA_CORTE, FORMAT(CORTES.C13,'d','eu') AS FECHA_CORTE
            --CORTES.C9 AS CAJA_CORTE
          ,SUM((ISNULL(EFECTIVO.EFECTIVO,0)-ISNULL(GENERAL.CAMBIO,0)-ISNULL(DEV_EFE.DEV_EFEC,0)+ISNULL(ANTICIPO.ANTICIPO,0) +ISNULL(RETIROS.ING,0)+ISNULL(RETIROS.RETI,0)- ISNULL(RETIROS.RETIDD,0))) AS EFECTIVO,
           SUM(GENERAL.TARJETA) AS TARJETA, SUM(GENERAL.VALE) AS VALE, SUM(GENERAL.CHEQUE) AS CHEQUE, SUM(GENERAL.DEPOSITO) AS DEPOSITO, SUM((GENERAL.ANTICIPO-ISNULL(ANTICIPO.ANTICIPO,0))) AS ANTICIPO
          ,SUM(GENERAL.MONEDERO) AS MONEDERO
    FROM KDPOS AS CORTES 
    LEFT JOIN KDUV AS VENDEDORES ON VENDEDORES.C2=CORTES.C10
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT EFECTIVO.C11 AS CAJAR, EFECTIVO.C44 AS FOLIOR, SUM(CAST( EFECTIVO.C88 AS DECIMAL(15,2))) AS EFECTIVO 
        FROM KDM1 AS EFECTIVO 
        WHERE EFECTIVO.C2='U' AND EFECTIVO.C3='D' AND EFECTIVO.C4='10' AND EFECTIVO.C5='1' AND EFECTIVO.C88<>''
        GROUP BY EFECTIVO.C11, EFECTIVO.C44
        UNION ALL
        SELECT EFECTIVO_RAP.C11 AS CAJAR, EFECTIVO_RAP.C44 AS FOLIOR, SUM(CAST( EFECTIVO_RAP.C88 AS DECIMAL(15,2))) AS EFECTIVO 
        FROM KDM1 AS EFECTIVO_RAP 
        WHERE EFECTIVO_RAP.C2='U' AND EFECTIVO_RAP.C3='D' AND EFECTIVO_RAP.C4='75' AND EFECTIVO_RAP.C5='1'AND EFECTIVO_RAP.C88<>''
        GROUP BY EFECTIVO_RAP.C11, EFECTIVO_RAP.C44
    ) AS EFECTIVO ON EFECTIVO.CAJAR=CORTES.C9 AND EFECTIVO.FOLIOR=CORTES.C6
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT DOCTOS.C11 AS CAJA, DOCTOS.C44 AS FOLIO_CAJA,
            SUM(CAST((CASE WHEN DOCTOS.C86='' THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), REPLACE(DOCTOS.C86, CHAR(0), '')) END) AS DECIMAL(15,2))) AS TARJETA
            ,SUM(CAST((CASE WHEN DOCTOS.C87='' THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), REPLACE(DOCTOS.C87, CHAR(0), '')) END) AS DECIMAL(15,2))) AS VALE
            ,SUM(DOCTOS.C49) AS CHEQUE
            ,SUM(CAST((CASE WHEN DOCTOS.C82='' THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), REPLACE(DOCTOS.C82, CHAR(0), '')) END) AS DECIMAL(15,2))) AS DEPOSITO
            ,SUM(CAST((CASE WHEN DOCTOS.C136='' THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), REPLACE(DOCTOS.C136, CHAR(0), '')) END) AS DECIMAL(15,2))) AS ANTICIPO
            ,SUM(CAST((CASE WHEN DOCTOS.C92='' THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), REPLACE(DOCTOS.C92, CHAR(0), '')) END) AS DECIMAL(15,2))) AS MONEDERO
            ,SUM(CAST((CASE WHEN DOCTOS.C84='' THEN 0 ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), REPLACE(DOCTOS.C84, CHAR(0), '')) END) AS DECIMAL(15,2))) AS CAMBIO
        FROM KDM1 AS DOCTOS
        WHERE DOCTOS.C9='20190201' --AND DOCTOS.C44='0000104'
        GROUP BY DOCTOS.C11, DOCTOS.C44
    ) AS GENERAL ON GENERAL.CAJA=CORTES.C9 AND GENERAL.FOLIO_CAJA=CORTES.C6
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT DEVOLUCIONES.C11 AS CAJA_DEV, DEVOLUCIONES.C44 AS FOLIO_DEV, SUM(DEVOLUCIONES.C16) AS DEV_EFEC 
        FROM KDM1 AS DEVOLUCIONES 
        WHERE DEVOLUCIONES.C2='U' AND DEVOLUCIONES.C3='A' AND DEVOLUCIONES.C4='20' AND DEVOLUCIONES.C5='1'
        GROUP BY DEVOLUCIONES.C11, DEVOLUCIONES.C44
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DEVOLUCIONES_RAP.C11 AS CAJA_DEV, DEVOLUCIONES_RAP.C44 AS FOLIO_DEV, SUM(DEVOLUCIONES_RAP.C16) AS DEV_EFEC 
        FROM KDM1 AS DEVOLUCIONES_RAP
        WHERE DEVOLUCIONES_RAP.C2='U' AND DEVOLUCIONES_RAP.C3='A' AND DEVOLUCIONES_RAP.C4='76' AND DEVOLUCIONES_RAP.C5='1'
        GROUP BY DEVOLUCIONES_RAP.C11, DEVOLUCIONES_RAP.C44
    ) AS DEV_EFE ON DEV_EFE.CAJA_DEV=CAJA AND DEV_EFE.FOLIO_DEV=CORTES.C6
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT ANTICIPOS.C11 AS CAJA_ANTI, ANTICIPOS.C44 AS FOLIO_ANTI, SUM(CAST( ANTICIPOS.C88 AS FLOAT)) AS ANTICIPO 
        FROM KDM1 AS ANTICIPOS
        WHERE ANTICIPOS.C2='U' AND ANTICIPOS.C3='A' AND ANTICIPOS.C4='40' AND ANTICIPOS.C5='1'
        GROUP BY ANTICIPOS.C11, ANTICIPOS.C44
    ) AS ANTICIPO ON ANTICIPO.CAJA_ANTI=CORTES.C9 AND ANTICIPO.FOLIO_ANTI=CORTES.C6
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT RETIROS.C1 AS CVE_SUC, RETIROS.C2 AS GEN, RETIROS.C3 AS NAT, RETIROS.C4 AS GPO, RETIROS.C5 AS TIP, RETIROS.C6 AS FOL, ISNULL(CASE WHEN RETIROS.C8='RETIRO' THEN (CASE WHEN RETIROS.C20='1' THEN (SUM(RETIROS.C9)*-1) END) END, 0) AS RETIDD, 
        ISNULL(CASE WHEN RETIROS.C8='RETIRO' THEN (CASE WHEN RETIROS.C20<>'1' THEN (SUM(RETIROS.C9)*-1) END) END, 0) AS RETI,
        ISNULL(CASE WHEN RETIROS.C8<>'RETIRO' THEN SUM(RETIROS.C9) END, 0) AS ING
        FROM KDM7 AS RETIROS
        GROUP BY RETIROS.C1, RETIROS.C2, RETIROS.C3, RETIROS.C4, RETIROS.C5, RETIROS.C6, RETIROS.C8, RETIROS.C20
    ) AS RETIROS ON RETIROS.CVE_SUC=CORTES.C1 AND RETIROS.GEN=CORTES.C2 AND RETIROS.NAT=CORTES.C3  AND RETIROS.GPO=CORTES.C4 AND RETIROS.TIP=CORTES.C5 AND RETIROS.FOL=CORTES.C6
    WHERE --CORTES.C1='"&suc&"' AND CORTES.C2='"&gen&"' AND CORTES.C3='"&nat&"' AND CORTES.C4='"&gpo&"' AND CORTES.C5='"&tip&"' AND 
    CORTES.C13='20190201' AND CORTES.C16='0' AND CORTES.C6='0000104'
    GROUP BY  CORTES.C1, CORTES.C2, CORTES.C3, CORTES.C4, CORTES.C5, CORTES.C9, FORMAT(CORTES.C13,'d','eu')
    --GROUP BY  CORTES.C1

-- Aquí es donde realmente cambiamos filas por columnas
SELECT Columna, Valor
FROM   
   (select EFECTIVO, TARJETA, VALE, CHEQUE, DEPOSIT, ANTICIPO, MONEDERO 
   from @datos) p  
UNPIVOT  
   (Valor FOR Columna IN   
      (EFECTIVO, TARJETA, VALE, CHEQUE, DEPOSIT, ANTICIPO, MONEDERO)  
)AS unpvt;  
GO
```

Comment: SI ME SIRVIO MUCHAS GRACIAS SOLO UNA DUDA QUE PASA SI QUIERO AGREGAR MAS OPCIONES EJEMPLO, UNA DONDE TENGO EFECTIVO 10 Y OTRO EFECTIVO 20

Comment: No pasaría nada, puedes ajustar la consulta fácilmente para que aparezcan ambas metiendo los dos campos. Si te ha servido, no olvides por favor marcarla como respuesta. Gracias